# send email notification to a profile when lead is created

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, apex-email-service

I'm trying to send an email to user a & b, when ever a on lead (created & updated) & the appointment info is available. Usually, i can do this by writing an workflow, but unfortunately, i cant do that(Limitation). is there any other way ?
Can i write a trigger events before update before insert ? some sample code would be great. 
really appreciate guys.

Comment: To start with it has to be after insert, after update you do not want emails to be sent out before the lead is created in the system ( what if the create/ update fails) . Having said that how many leads are you speaking of, the data volume decides if it is a trigger or batch approach. Also take into consideration that you may be sending an email flood when you insert/update  multiple leads into the system using ETL/ data loading tool.

Comment: @rao - if the create/update fails the entire transaction will be rolled back including any emails.  Emails are only sent when the transaction commits.

Comment: oops @bobbuzzard you are right slipped away a bit from basics

Comment: Thank you guys, i was able to use a workflow for this. That solved the problem. :)